# Call a method n number of times

Tags: c#, .net

```
int noOfAttempts = 3;
void StartServer();
bool IsServerRunning();
```

I need to re-attempt `StartServer()` 3 times based on result from `IsServerRunnig()`. Something like this:

```
StartServer();
if (!IsServerRunning())
{
    StartServer();
    if (!IsServerRunning())
    {
        StartServer();
        if (!IsServerRunning())
        {
            StartServer();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to use for loops or the ugly code like above. Is there a better way of doing this? A way in which, I won't have to change my code if `noOfAttempts` change in future?

EDIT:
**I'm expecting something from the "delegate" concept (If possible).**

Comment: Why do you not want to use for loops? Seems like a good structure for this.

Comment: @Oded: if noOfAttempts changes, then I will have to add another if condition to the code.

Comment: I don't see why that would be, not if you use for loops correctly.

Comment: @Oded OP is right, `while` loop is more flexible for this situation, IMO.

Comment: The point is: I wanted to avoid loops in my code :)

Comment: A `while` loop is great here, but why on earth *must* you have something using a `delegate`? Don't over-complicate things.

Comment: @Sandeep I'd love to avoid code in my projects. When you want to repeat something in your applications, you have to use loops (I don't even want to mention `goto`).

Comment: You _should_ be using loops for this. It makes 0 sense to go for something more complicated and out of the ordinary.

Comment: What's wrong if I want to try out something new? It might help me in other complex scenarios. It's a well-known fact that loops are designed to use for this kinda things.. but just trying an attempt out of the box..

Comment: @Sandeep - Because trying something that is "out of the box" for something this simple is sort of silly.  Complicated code is bad...and that is exactly what any other option would give you..complicated unreadable code you don't understand.

Comment: Attempting to avoid loops in code? My dear sir, loops are one of 3 basic structures of any program. Without them, there will be things you can't implement. If you can solve something with a loop easily, why look for a more complicated solution?  Prithee, kind sir, look away from this foolishness!  It serves you poorly, I assure you!

Comment: You can create a `list<>` of strings in correct order and use an `each` and `reflection` to get the methods to be called....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPD**:

Seems like you actually want(ed) some neat way to describe retry logic. In this case look at transient-fault-handling libraries such as [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).

---

Ok.

```
3.TimesUntil(IsServerRunning, StartServer);
```

Delegate magic here:

```
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static void TimesWhile(this int count, Func<bool> predicate, Action action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count && predicate(); i++) 
           action();
    }
    public static void TimesUntil(this int count, Func<bool> predicate, Action action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count && !predicate(); i++) 
            action();
    }
}
```

**To esteemed downvoters:**
It's just for fun and I'd never write this code for real projects.

Comment: `i` should be incremented each time, otherwise you'll just go until success (or forever in the case of failure)

Comment: It will work, and it uses delegates.... But it's a nonsense. Its unnecesarily complicated. Don't understand, why don't use loop for such simple task.

Comment: @mlorbetske, thanks, I forgot :)

Comment: @Jakub Szułakiewicz, because Sandeep asked. And just for fun of course)

Comment: But oh my... OP may not want to use this as it still contains a 'for' loop

Comment: Good answer, however the original question stated "no for loops" which implies while loops would be absaloutley fine.  Good answer none the less.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a while loop

```
int counter = 0;
while(counter < 3 && !IsServerRunning()) {
    StartServer();
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you go no loops...

```
private void Start(int numberOfAttempts)
{
    if (numberOfAttempts == 0)
        return;

    StartServer();

    if (!IsServerRunning())
        Start(numberOfAttempts-1);
}
```

Comment: Make it `Start(--numberOfAttempts)` or `Start(numberOfAttempts-1)` otherwise you'll face infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

As everybody already noted a while or for loop is really the most easiest part to solve this problem.

If you really want to setup something really advanced for this stuff take a look at the [trampoline function question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189725/what-is-a-trampoline-function) or take a look into the [article from Bart](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/11/08/jumping-the-trampoline-in-c-stack-friendly-recursion.aspx). With this approach you would be able to avoid the loop (hence i don't think it would be worth in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
while (numRetries > 0 && !IsServerRunning) {
    StartServer();
    numRetries--;
}
```

If you feel adventurous, you could also use `goto` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberOfAttempts = 3;

do
{
    StartServer();
    numberOfAttempts--;
} 
while(!IsServerRunning() && numberOfAttempts > 0)
```

UPDATE: Thus this operations are closely-related, you can create method

```
bool TryStartServer()
{
     StartServer();
     return IsServerRunning();
}
```

And second one which, will try to start server several times (and returns the result of operation)

```
bool TryStartServer(int numberOfAttemtps)
{
    for(int attempt = 0; attempt < numberOfAttempts; attempt++)
        if (TryStartServer)
            return true;

    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a delegate if you really wanted.. (perhaps for a library of reusable things?)

```
public void CallFunctionNTimes(Action func, int nTimes, params bool[] conditions) {
    int callCounter = 0;

    while (callCounter < nTimes && conditions.All(x => x == true)) {
        func();
        callCounter++;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
CallFunctionNTimes(StartServer, 3, !IsServerRunning /* Other stuff too if you want */);
```

.. not really much different than the other answers except its re-usable I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

How about the do.. while(false) loop? (joking, but seriously I've seen it in code before)

```
int numTries;

        do
        {
            if(numTries == 0)
                break;

            StartServer();
            numTries--;

            if (!IsServerRunning)
                continue;
        } while (false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably make it a builtin functionality of the `StartServer` method itself. Something like this (just a proof of concept):

```
public class ServerNotRunningException : Exception { /*No content here*/ }

public void StartServer(int attempts = 3)
{
    try
    {
        //attempt to start server
        if(!IsServerRunning()) // or check something available in your method
            throw new ServerNotRunningException();
    }
    catch(ServerNotRunningException ex)
    {
        // you should log ex.ToString() here!
        if(attempts>0) StartServer(attempts-1); //try again!
        else throw new ServerNotRunningException(); //mission failed, bubble up!
    }
}
```

usage:

```
StartServer();
//or, to make it try i.e. 5 times
StartServer(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better to have the retry logic totally separate from the main code:

```
void Attempt(Action action, Func<bool> ensure, int noOfAttempts)
{
   while (noOfAttempts-- > 0 && !ensure())
   {
       action();
   }
}
```

and then:

```
Attempt(action:StartServer, ensure:IsServerRunning, noOfAttempts:3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun

```
var calls = Enumerable.Repeat<List<string>>(new List<string>() { "IsServerRunning", "StartServer" }, noOfAttempts).ToList();
calls.ForEach(new Action<List<string>>(
    delegate(List<string> item)
    {
        // Use reflection here to create calls to the elements of item
    }
));
```