# Stack overflow when using large exponent for Exponentiation by Squaring

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion

I am trying to calculate very large 'long' type numbers using a recursive Exponentiation by Squaring algorithm, as seen below. I am encountering stack overflow errors when increasing the size of the exponent, and I want to find out how I can allow it to loop and not take up so much space on the stack. I want to achieve this without using the Math library, so only in vanilla Java code.

```
public long exp(long base, long exponent, long accum){
    if (power > 0) {
        return exp(base, exponent - 1, accum * base);
    } else {
        return accum;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (power > 0) {` yeah power to the people, but where is it declared, where does it change?

Comment: There is no squaring here, and no need for recursion either. There is a well-known iterative algorithm that *does* involve squaring and that is far more efficient than this.

Comment: This is not the "exponentiation by squaring" algorithm.  This is just straight repeated multiplication.

Comment: `power` should be `exponent`, and IMHO, you have to use loops(`for` or `while`) to achieve this.

Comment: And you aren't handling the zero case correctly.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the power variable was renamed to put on here and in my code is the same as the exponent variable.

Comment: Which still leaves you with the zero-exponent bug and the complete lack of squaring.

Comment: Perform the tail recursion elimination yourself and transform the recursion into a loop. Or have a look at Trampolining, e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189725/what-is-a-trampoline-function

Comment: @meng Don't edit questions to show the answer. Edit rejected.